# facebook like button fb_app

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have been trying to do the like button on my html file, at http://2011w.streetvoice.com/ but I can't get it to work, please check the error code below, thanks!

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"requires_login":false,"error_info":{"brief":"No       administrators were specified.","full":"The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators using either a \"fb:app_id\" meta tag, or using a \"fb:admins\" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users.","errorUri":"\/connect\/connect_to_node_error.php?title=No+administrators+were+specified.&body=The+page+failed+to+provide+a+valid+list+of+administrators.+It+needs+to+specify+the+administrators+using+either+a+\u002522fb\u00253Aapp_id\u002522+meta+tag\u00252C+or+using+a+\u002522fb\u00253Aadmins\u002522+meta+tag+to+specify+a+comma-delimited+list+of+Facebook+users.&hash=AQCGAzIHN8caKdYy"},"show_error":true,"node_type":"ExternalLink","node_id":"10150389878017540","edge_type":"ExternalLinkLike","connect_text":0,"success":true,"already_connected":true,"user_profile":{"name":"Sam","profile_url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/genxstylez","pic_square":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-snc4\/275759_544981545_6579157_q.jpg"},"story_fbid":0,"is_admin":false,"admin_url":""}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It throws because you didn't specify facebook id for admin(s)

Try to add this code between **< head >** tags:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR-FACEBOOK-ID"/>
```